# How do I copy all data from a row from a specific number of columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying data from a large table in one sheet to a smaller table to show only the necessary rows of data needed to request quotes from suppliers for parts. I am using the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, R As Integer
Set sh1 = Sheets("Breakdown & Analysis")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Mail Merge")
R = 2

For Each c1 In sh1.Range("O8", sh1.Range("O8").End(xlDown))
    If c1.Value = "Yes" Then     'If the part is specified as Yes to be quoted
        sh2.Rows(R) = c1.EntireRow.Value   'Copies entire row
        R = R + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Rather than copy the entire row, where I have left the comment stating such, I would like it to transfer columns 1 - 20 only from that row.

How do I edit my code to do this?

Comment: what is `c1`  ? is it a `Range` in `sh1`  ? if you are looking to scan the Range in Column "O" and looking for dynamic last row in Column "O", change your line to `For Each c1 In sh1.Range("O8:O" & sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: 'c' is the 'CurrentRegion' function, it allows me to store cell data temporarily without declaring a variable, which is ideal for its purpose. That particular line of code is checking each cell down column O. O is not the last row, and this part of the code is working fine. 2 lines down, I am using that cell reference in the current region to identify the row that I would like to copy the data from. However I cant figure out how to specify the columns within that row that I want to pull data from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long
    Dim c1 As Range

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Breakdown & Analysis")
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Mail merge")
    R = 2

    With sh1
        For Each c1 In .Range("O8", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp))
            If c1.Value = "Yes" Then
                sh2.Cells(R, 1).Resize(, 20).Value = .Cells(c1.Row, 1).Resize(, 20).Value
                R = R + 1
            End If
        Next c1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 'c1.Resize(, 20).Value' - caused the copied cells to begin from cell "O8", which I should have mentioned was within the table and not to the far left. I therefore kept the left half of your statement, and kept the right half of my original statement. Resulting in the cutting of the entire row to 20 columns. - Perfect, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll edit the answer to account for your clarification but following a slightly different pattern